# how to read a specific line and print a specific position in this line using python

Tags: python

how to read specific lines from the text file, which contains several lines with the same character of "!". My goal is to find  the last line and print the position number four "[4]".

my file.txt:

```
     1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000
     1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000
     1.0000   1.0000   1.0002   0.9879   0.8682   0.6437  -0.0000  -0.0000
.
.
.
.
!    T   E              =    -122.1058
.
.
.
!    T   E              =    -123.1050
.
.
.
!    T   E              =    -125.10584323
```

my script (not working):

```
import sys, os
import datetime
import time as t

oTE_list = []
oTE = []

with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    text = f.readlines()
for line in text:
  if line[0] == '!':
    oTE_list.append(line[4])


# Change Lists To Number Format
for item in oTE_list:
  oTE.append(float(item))


for idx, item in enumerate(oTE_list):        
    if idx == len(oTE_list) - 1:
        print(item)
number5 = (item)
```

on the other hand, I managed with bash:

```
grep ! file.txt | awk 'END{print $5}'
```

the result should be like this: **-125.10584323**

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple enough, I don't know why you complicated it.

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
lines = [line for line in f.readlines() if line[0]=="!"]
number = float(lines[-1].split()[4])
```

Explanation:
`f.readlines()` reads all lines and make a list of lines.
`lines` is a list of lines starting with `!`.
`lines[-1]` selects the last lines from the list.
`lines[-1].split()` will make a list of words in the last line. (split at `" "` (spaces))
`lines[-1].split()[4]` will select the 5th word from the list of words.
`float(lines[-1].split()[4])` will convert the word to float.

Comment: f = open("file.txt", "r")
lines = [line for line in f.readlines() if line[0]=="!"]
number = float(lines[-1].split()[4])thank you very much, a simple and very effective script.
a big thank-you.

Answer (score 2):

This is even more simple considering its the line what you want to print

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#import re
with open("file1.txt") as f:
  lines = f.readlines()[-1]
  lastline = lines.split()[-1]
  print lastline
```

> Desired ouput from the run..

```
bash-4.1$ ./file1.py
-125.10584323
```

> In case you want all lines which are starting with `"!"` positionining
>   into the last index value then you can use below ....

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
with open("file1.txt") as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  for line in lines:
    if "!" in line:
      line = line.split()[-1]
      print line
```

> Output value will be beow ..

```
bash-4.1$ ./file1_dup.py
-122.1058
-123.1050
-125.10584323
```

Comment: thanks for all the world,
the three scripts of **Frito**, **Jithin Pavithran** and **Kran march** very well.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for here is [how to cut and slice your string](http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/). I've tweaked the code you supplied above to include this string slice. Check out the first for loop :-)

```
def main():
    oTE_list = []
    oTE = []

    with open("file.txt","r") as f:
        text = f.readlines()
    for line in text:
        if line[0] == '!':
            equals_index = line.index('=')
            # Get everything after the equal and remove extra whitespace
            after_equal = line[equals_index+1:].strip()
            oTE_list.append(after_equal)

    # Change Lists To Number Format
    for item in oTE_list:
        oTE.append(float(item))

    for idx, item in enumerate(oTE_list):
        if idx == len(oTE_list) - 1:
            print(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running this I get the result:

```
C:\Python35\python.exe C:/Users/Frito/GitSource/help/sample.py
-125.10584323
```

Now you may be wondering how this is working. Your input is a bit difficult as there isn't really a good way that I know of to remove all the spaces in between the `!`, `T`, `E`, `=` and `<number>` fields. In this case by looking at your data I opted to find the equal sign and just look at the data after it. The line `equals_index = line.index('=')` finds the position in the string where the equal sign is at. This "position" includes spaces. This is can be seen by looking at the string's position 24. For example `print(line[24])`.

Now that we can compute where the equal sign is at we can then get everything after the equal sign. In your example this is the number you wish to print to the screen with some extra spaces. If you were to print the string "   abc   " directly using the `print` command it would print with three spaces before and after the `abc`. The `.strip()` function in python removes those extra spaces.

When we combine these two approaches above we can find your number and print just that number. I hope this helps!

Comment: If Jithin Pavithran's version of code makes sense I'd definitely use that version as it is the way you'll typically see things done in Python.

Comment: Hi , dear Frito thank you very much, 
your script interests me, but try to run it ..... as I am not very talented .... I take a lot of time.


right now I want to run it but an error message appears

Comment: error message  : ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-122.10584323 Ry'

Comment: "Ok" ,  that's good:
the mistake is that I did not remove my two lines:

     for item in oTE_list:
         oTE.append ((item))