# print last line from the variable output in python

Tags: python

I am looking to get the last line produced from the `line` variable

```
bash-4.1$ cat file1_dup.py
#!/usr/bin/python
with open("file1.txt") as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  for line in lines:
    if "!" in line:
      line = line.split()[-1].strip()
      print line
```

> output i am getting is as follows ..

```
-122.1058
-123.1050
-125.10584323
```

> The result i wanted to be printed out is

`-125.10584323`

> Moreover, i got the hint from some goghling and getting the output
>   desired but that seems bit complicated to me at the point ..

```
bash-4.1$ cat file2_dup.py
#!/usr/bin/python
def file_read_from_tail(fname,n):
  with open(fname) as f:
    f=f.read().splitlines()
    lines=[x for x in f]
    for i in range(len(lines)-n,len(lines)):
      line = lines[i].split()[-1]
      #line = line.split()[-1]
      print line
file_read_from_tail('file1.txt',1)
```

> this yeilds teh desired as folows..

```
bash-4.1$ ./file2_dup.py
-125.10584323
```

PS: i just borrow the question for the sake of intrest from:
[how to read a specific line and print a specific position in this line using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47257185/how-to-read-a-specific-line-and-print-a-specific-position-in-this-line-using-pyt/47258041#47258041)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could test if the new line is smaller as the one before like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
res_line = 0
with open("file1.txt") as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  for line in lines:
    if "!" in line:
      line = float(line.split()[-1].strip())
      if res_line > line:
          res_line = line
  print res_line
```

Comment: user1 .. this simple prints 0

Comment: I added `float()` so the comparison works. try again please

Comment: its works.. can you explain the code , how it works.. specially `res_line = line`

Comment: how it works.. specially `res_line = line` -> res_line (a variable to store the final result) will capture the value of line only if it is lower than the last captured value (inside the for loop execution). If line values were positive it wouldn't capture any unless you change the first line with `res_line = 0` to start with another value.

Comment: @progmatico, thnx for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

you can use `enumerate()` to get the lines indexed in a loop:

```
with open("file1.txt", "rt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line, content in enumerate(lines):
        # apply your logic to line and/or content here
        # by adding ifs to select the lines you want...
        print line, content.strip() # do your thing
```

will output (just to illustrate because I didn't specify any conditions in code above):

```
0 -122.1058
1 -123.1050
2 -125.10584323
3
```

or in alternative select your specific line with a condition in a listcomp
by using this code instead:

```
with open("file1.txt", "rt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    result = [ content.strip() for line, content in enumerate(lines)
         if line == len(lines) - 2] # creates a list with
                                    # only the last line
    print result[0]
```

that will output:

```
-125.10584323
```

Comment: I am just selecting the value from last line, sorry i didn't read the link you gave. it looks you wanted to filter lines with `!` and also select the minimum value...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
print [line.split()[-1].strip() for line in lines if '!' in line][-1]
```

Comment: O.Suleiman .. this prints the output multiple time, i tried it already

Comment: @Karn... Can you provide a snippet of the file?

Comment: i have refernced the link in my orignal Question which will give you all info , please see if you get that.

Answer (score 0):

I see a better way by creating an empty list and appending the value comes from the condition and then choose the Index of your choice and list the output , this is good in the sense that it can be used for any line of your intrest which you require to pick.

Lets Suppose i wana the last second line then it can be resuable putting the value in the print section  `print(lst[-2])` , which will print the last index of second line..

```
#!/usr/bin/python
file = open('file1.txt', 'r')
lst = list()
for line in file:
    if "!" in line:
        x= line.split()
        lst.append(x[-1])

print(lst[-1])
```